# How to restore anaconda and python environment?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

So last night I was using my Anaconda-Navigator when i suddenly crashed. Afterwards, when I try to run it from the command line it gave me  this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mango/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anaconda_navigator'
```

Now at first I thought I can re-install anaconda navigator but when I went to run some python scripts I had written many of my packets was not loading.

I am suspecting something is wrong with my environment but no matter how much I try I cannot seem to figure out the issue.

Please if you have anyway of guiding me that would be wonderful

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435579/cannot-open-anaconda-suddenly

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately i get the same error when I try to run conda