# Anaconda 2020.02 on Windows 10 64, problems with navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed a fresh Anaconda version 2020.02 on my Windows 10 64, when I run anaconda-navigator script from Anaconda Prompt, I get this error:

```
    (base) PS C:\Users\Alessio> anaconda-navigator
    PySide2/__init__.py: Unable to import shiboken2 from D:\Anaconda3\Scripts, 
    D:\Anaconda3\python37.zip, D:\Anaconda3\DLLs, D:\Anaconda3\lib, D:\Anaconda3, 
    C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages, D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages, 
    D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32, D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib, 
    D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
      from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
      from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
      from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
      raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
      qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Running pip freeze the versions of PySide2 and shiboken2 are the same:

- shiboken2: 5.14.2
- PySide2: 5.14.2

but I notice that PySide is missing, and is impossible to install manually because of Python interpreter level

maybe have to reinstall qtpy?

Any idea?

Ok, solved
I had first to remove .condarc file in my home directory 
and run

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

but had still the same problem, finally i run

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyqt5
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyside2
```

And now is working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open anaconda suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435579/cannot-open-anaconda-suddenly)

Comment: Updating those libraries with pip might be a bad idea, be careful.

Comment: Question, why is a bad idea? I saw a lot of people using pip install instead of anaconda install , yeah now is working correctly.

Comment: There’s a nice article from the Anaconda people which covers this topic [here](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).

Comment: I know all this "concern" and stuff about pip and conda and environment etc, by the way is a 2018 article and now the conda version is 4.8.3

Comment: Alex... The conda article is still important to follow (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).  Conda and pip should not be interleaved willy-nilly. Follow best practices.  "...when combining conda and pip, it is best to use an isolated conda environment. Only after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible should pip be used to install any remaining software. If modifications are needed to the environment, it is best to create a new environment rather than running conda after pip."

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has a fix that worked for you @Alex, but I wanted to post what worked for me and I think it should be "safer" than what you posted since it doesn't use pip.

On a fresh install of Anaconda 2020-02 x86_64 I did the following:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda install -c conda-forge pyside2
```

After the above I was able to start `anaconda-navigator` without any issues.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Thanks jp36. After your 3 steps (and seerval other tried before that) I was still not able to run Scripts>anaconda-navigator.exe (still error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide' etc)... However, I WAS (finally) able to launch the Navigator GUI, via a shortcut pointing to to Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py