# Anaconda doesn't launch

Tags: python, windows, qt, anaconda, pyside

I successfully installed Anaconda3 on my Windows 10 laptop but when I try to launch Navigator (or any other Anaconda app) it doesn't start. When typing `anaconda-navigator` on Anaconda Prompt this is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it several times but nothing changed. I already tried `conda update conda` and `conda update navigator` but the problem still persists. I also tried to install Anaconda2 and it worked perfectly fine, so how can I make Anaconda3 work?

Comment: Since it says "No module named 'PySide'", have you tried installing PySide? And also probably Qt?

Comment: Yes, I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open anaconda suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435579/cannot-open-anaconda-suddenly)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not. I already tried all that stuff.