# Unable to run anaconda neither anaconda-prompt on Windows

Tags: anaconda

I have a following problem. I am not able to run anaconda navigator, neither anaconda-prompt after anaconda3 installation.

Nothing happens when I click on anaconda-navigator.exe as saved in C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\Scripts. When I check environmental variables paths I have there C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\Scripts.

When I try to run anaconda navigator from cmd I get this error:

```
C:\Users\misak>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\misak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I tried to reinstall Anaconda many times, co the problem seems to be somewhere else. Can you help my please?

Comment: Have you tried running anaconda navigator from the command line? Is Conda working correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open anaconda suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435579/cannot-open-anaconda-suddenly)

Comment: Unfortunately no. When I try `conda update conda` I get this error message: `Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'`

Comment: It sounds like there are multiple things which might be broken, you should consider just removing and reinstalling Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks, but I tries it many times and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure Anaconda was completely removed? Did you follow the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) ?