# Anaconda Navigator won't open, and conda won't update

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Yesterday Anaconda Navigator would open and work fine, but today when I try to open it, it doesn't come up. The only thing I can think is that it might be related to the fact that I updated pyreadstat yesterday using `conda update pyreadstat`.

Looking around, most of the recommendations for when Anaconda Navigator won't open suggest you cd to the Scripts directory where Anaconda is stored, update conda (`conda update conda`), then update Anaconda Navigator (`conda update anaconda-navigator`).

I did this:

```
cd C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Scripts
conda update conda
```

And got this error:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
        if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 714, in use_only_tar_bz2
        import conda_package_handling.api
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 6, in <module>
        from six import string_types as _string_types
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

Of course I thought "ah, well I'll install six, then" and tried `conda install six`, which gave me the same error, so now I'm stumped. I don't know why this module "six" would be related to my updating pyreadstat.

I did then try pip installing six, which allowed me to update conda, but I still can't open Anaconda Navigator by clicking, and when I try to run it by just typing `anaconda-navigator` within the Scripts directory, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ldulude\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Comment: Look at this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435579/cannot-open-anaconda-suddenly. Another thing is that you should activate the base conda env, that will make Scripts available on the path and fix other things. Do conda init (I think)

Comment: You could also start using a separate conda env or vituslenv per project so that you dont get into this kind of situation ... A bit radical but you could reinstall anacinda/miniconda from scratch and start using induvidual environments

Comment: Ultimately I did uninstall & reinstall Anaconda